# Meaning of "acquisition in a single volume" (CT scanning)

Tags: terminology, medical-imaging, ct-scans

From a [research paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6205842/): (Richards, et al. 2018).

> A number of integrated strategies were used to achieve this consistently low dose, including; prospective ECG-gated acquisition, lowest possible tube current and voltage, IR (AIDR3D image reconstruction algorithm) and meticulous attention to patient preparation, both pre scan (heart rate control) and during the scan (reduction in volume of coverage to minimal size possible whilst allowing complete **acquisition in a single volume.**

What is the meaning of this phrase?

Does it mean that the scanner obtained all the necessary data in a single pass, requiring no second turn around the patient's body? Or maybe several rotations were needed, but still the data was obtained "in a single take"?

How would acquisition in two volumes differ from acquisition "in a single volume"?

### References

Richards, C. E., Dorman, S., John, P., Davies, A., Evans, S., Ninan, T., Martin, D., Kannoly, S., Roberts-Davies, G., Ramsey, M., & Obaid, D. R. (2018). Low-radiation and high image quality coronary computed tomography angiography in "real-world" unselected patients. *World journal of radiology, 10*(10), 135–142. doi: [10.4329/wjr.v10.i10.135](https://doi.org/10.4329/wjr.v10.i10.135) pmcid: [6205842](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6205842/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Acquisition in a single volume” means an image obtained by a single rotation of a scanner ("single gantry rotation"). It covers up to 16 cm of the body.

"Wide volume imaging" includes repeated single volume imaging of adjacent areas and then combining them into a single image. So, two volumes would cover up to 32 cm, three volumes up to 48 cm, etc.

*Source: [Living in a Volume World: Applications for 320-detector row CT in a community-based hospital, Canon Medical Systems, USA](https://us.medical.canon/download/aq-one-vision-ctrp2019us)*